# C# Bowling Game Calculation Issue

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have problem with my C# Bowling game and I would appericate some help I'll try to explain the code as well as i can. I've been trying to solve this issue for a long time and no success yet.

The calculation works fine but the only problem is my strike, the strike should count 10 + the next 2 coming throws.

So what my program does:

if you get a strike the first value will be set to 10, then I enter another strike and value is set to 21 but should be 20. The second box should then have a value of 30.

So first I have 3 arrays to hold all the textboxes

```
    summa = new TextBox[] { textBox14, textBox15, textBox16, textBox17, textBox18, textBox19 };
    slag1 = new TextBox[] { textBox1, textBox3, textBox5, textBox7, textBox9, textBox11 };
    slag2 = new TextBox[] { textBox2, textBox4, textBox6, textBox8, textBox10, textBox12 };
```

So I have 2 methods, `Slag1()` and `Slag2()` the strike runs in the `Slag1()` method.

This is the part i use for the calculation of the strike

```
if (strike == true)
        {
            GotStrike[omgang] = true;
        }
        //strike = false;

        //Kollar ifall textbox är lika med 10
        if (slag1[omgang].Text == "10")
        {
            //Om text box är lika med 10 ändra värdet till X
            //Lägg till 10 poäng på total
            //Skriv ut värdet på summa (textbox)
            Arbetar = true;
            slag1[omgang].Text = "X";
            total += 9;
            summa[omgang].Text = total.ToString();
            omgang++;
            if (omgang == 6)
            {
                omgang--;
            }
            strike = true;
        }
        else if (slag1[omgang].Text == "X")
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            checkSlag1 = Convert.ToInt32(slag1[omgang].Text);
            total += checkSlag1;
            summa[omgang].Text = total.ToString();

            if (strike == true)
            {
                if (omgang != 0)
                {
                    total += 10;
                    slag1[omgang - 1].Text = total.ToString();
                    if (omgang != 1)
                    {
                        slag1[omgang - 2].Text = total.ToString();
                    }
                    else
                    {

                    }
                }
                else
                {

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

It's kinda hard to explain but I hope you understand, please tell me if you don't understand so I'll write a better explanation.

I hope you know how a bowling game works, a strike = the first strike and the value of the next 2 coming strikes. So if i hit a strike i get the value of 10, strike 2 value of 10 and strike 3 value of 10. That's the total of index 0.

Comment: If you don't understand this part of the code your free to check the source code right here: http://pastebin.com/p6cttLX3

Comment: You've mixed UI and logic ([SoC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)). If you separate them it will be much easier to write tests to find out where things start to go wrong. [Bowling](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/xpepisode.htm) was also used in (I think) Kent Beck's book Test Driven Development.

Comment: Can you give an example of how I should structure my code? Since I have no iead of what your trying to tell me.

Comment: You should take a look at this book *Agile Principles, Patterns, and Practices in C# (Robert C. Martin)*. I agree that you should use **TDD* for this kind of issue, and this book will help with that and it also goes through building a bowling game.

Comment: I just want to be able to give +10 to the textboxes, lets say textbox1 is 10, textbox2 10 it should +10 on textbox 1 which gives me a value of 20 and then 20 + 10 on textbox 2. What I try to do is use `summa[omgang - 1] & summa[omgang - 2]` which should go back 1 round and then 2 rounds for each strike.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are having trouble with calculating the correct score for the bowling game, I would suggest to take out the bowling game mechanics, write tests that check if the different throws work correctly (ie normal, spare and strike). Then you can tinker with the code and when all tests pass, your scoring works. After that you can create any UI that uses the bowling game.

Also check the link I provided in the comment. The code is in Java but it is similar enough to C# and gives an example for a bowling game API with reasoning how they got to their particular design.

Your bowling game could look like this:
(I don't really know the bowling rules)

```
public class Bowling
{
     public void Throw(int count) // How do you call these things that you need to knock over...
     {
         Debug.Assert(count >= 0);
         Debug.Assert(count <= 12);
         // ... Lots of interesting code.
     }

     public int GetScore()
     {
          return 16;
     }
}
```

This code obviously doesn't work. The trick is to write tests that run "red" (=fail) and then to write code until the tests run "green" (=pass).

For these tests you can use a framework such as NUnit, ...

```
[TestClass]
public class BowlingTests
{
    [Test]
    public void ThrowNormal_NormalScore()
    {
        var b = new Bowling();
        b.Throw(5);
        b.Throw(6);

        Assert.That(b.GetScore(), Is.EqualTo(11));
    }

    public void ThrowSpare_SpecialScore()
    {
         var b = new Bowling();
         b.Throw(1);
         b.Throw(11); // = spare
         b.Throw(5);  // score counts for double?
         b.Throw(3);  // No double score

         Assert.That(b.GetScore(), Is.EqualTo(1 + 11 + (5 * 2) + 3));
    }

    // More tests for all the edge cases (strike, special end of game rules etc)
}
```

Comment: They are called Pins.